# How to add more default colors?

Tags: themes, block-editor, color-picker

I just reinstalled my website with the same theme and now the other default colors are gone. Only black is left.

Is there a way to add more default colors?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add more colors using the `add_theme_support` function as per the docs [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/themes/theme-support/#block-color-palettes)

```
add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette', array(
    array(
        'name' => __( 'strong magenta', 'themeLangDomain' ),
        'slug' => 'strong-magenta',
        'color' => '#a156b4',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => __( 'light grayish magenta', 'themeLangDomain' ),
        'slug' => 'light-grayish-magenta',
        'color' => '#d0a5db',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => __( 'very light gray', 'themeLangDomain' ),
         'slug' => 'very-light-gray',
        'color' => '#eee',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => __( 'very dark gray', 'themeLangDomain' ),
        'slug' => 'very-dark-gray',
        'color' => '#444',
    ),
) );
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to make a function that if I open that panel, then the second color with be automatically chosen?

Comment: I'm not sure you can - perhaps make it the first item in the list?

Comment: hmm, I thought the first item would be the default one. Say if I want the text to be normally black, I need to put black as the first one in the list. But even that, the first item is still not automatically chosen